# How to Pop-up/Alert in Seam? (Java)

Tags: java, popup, seam, alert

Thanks for your time!

I'm a Java developer that inherited an existing mostly-done Seam project (viewed with a browser) and am having a hard time tracing through where the errors are because I don't know how to send a message to the user (for debugging) at runtime. Both JOptionPane and System.out.println are not helpful (the former crashes the project). Is there code can I type (either in the Java or the xhtml files) that would send any type of message to the user?* A Pop-up (alert) is preferred but any way of tracing would be great! 
Thank you!

{*Preferably usable just like a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send a message to the user like you can with JOptionPane, and that's mostly because it's the Web.  Pushing data to the browser is possible, using some of the RichFaces components, but it I don't think you want to do that for debugging

When I'm debugging Seam, I use logging (slf4j), and break points in the java code.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It saved me a lot of time. Just to follow up in case anyone has a similar issue, I was mistaken in thinking I couldn't see the console output (thinking system.out.println would be useless). JBoss has a server.log file that contains all of the console output for the last run server. I can just search for my trigger names. However, if someone wanted to make their own personal log file that only contains their triggers, they could use the whole Buffered Reader/Writer method to make their own text file. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: You can actually go a step farther and manipulate the log config.  JBoss uses log4j configuration, so you can turn off everything but the classes you want to see.